# MySQL INNER JOIN with results of WHERE conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I want to be able to query a MySQL database to find siblings of a person just based on their parents and children. We're hypothetically assuming here that the children of a person's parents, and the parents of a person's children are the siblings of that person.

**people**

```
id  name
-----------
1   jonny
2   tom
3   sally
4   bill
5   katie
6   jessica
```

**rels**

```
id  parent  child
--------------------
1   2       3
2   5       6
3   2       1
4   1       6
5   1       4
6   6       2
```

I've been trying to figure out how to JOIN the two tables in a way that gives me those results, but I can't get it right.

```
SELECT people.id,people.name FROM people, rels
INNER JOIN rels children ON people.id = rels.parent
INNER JOIN rels siblings ON children.id = siblings.child
WHERE children.child = '1'
```

Comment: haha, sorry - typo :p got distracted while typing >_<

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT people.id,people.name  FROM people
   LEFT JOIN rels children ON people.id = children.parent
   LEFT JOIN rels siblings ON people.id = siblings.child
   WHERE children.child = '1'
   group by people.id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45ba3/105)

Comment: I think this is close, but sally should be returned as well. She is a child of tom, who is a parent of jonny. I tried " SELECT people.id,people.name  FROM people
   LEFT JOIN rels children ON people.id = children.parent
   LEFT JOIN rels parents ON people.id = parents.child
   LEFT JOIN rels siblings ON people.id = siblings.child
   WHERE children.child = '1' OR parents.parent = '1'
   group by people.id" - sorry for the formatting, but that returned a bill as well, who is just a child of jonny.

Comment: yes when children is 1 (jonny) then you got his parent (tom) and by your wish to get sally means you want get the brother/sister of the 1 entered (jonny) ? because sally and jonny have same parent. so you dont want get the parent , you want get brothers?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution using UNIONs, which I think will do for now. If anyone can come up with a purely JOIN based solution, I'd love to see it!

```
SELECT people.*,c.* FROM rels
   INNER JOIN rels c ON rels.parent = c.parent
   INNER JOIN people ON people.id = c.child
   WHERE rels.child = '1' AND people.id <> '1'

UNION

SELECT people.*,p.* FROM rels
   INNER JOIN rels p ON rels.child = p.child
   INNER JOIN people ON people.id = p.parent
   WHERE rels.parent = '1' AND people.id <> '1'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45ba3/103/0

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but this should work :

```
SELECT ppl.* from people as ppl
INNER JOIN rels AS par1 on ppl.id = par1.child
INNER JOIN rels as par2 on par2.parent = par1.parent
INNER JOIN people as sib on sib.id = par2.child
WHERE ppl.id = '3'
```

Explanation taking example of sally (id = 3)

From PPL select the person for whom siblings are to be found. (id = 3)

From PAR1 (Parent) select its parent. Parent = 2 is selected

From PAR2 (Parent) select same parent Parent = 2 is selected

From SIB (People) select details where id = 3,1

Do let me know if this does not work ...